# CPP write/read class into binary file

Tags: c++, file, class, binary, fstream

I have 3 files, main.cpp(main program), user.h(User class) and userlist.h(LinkedList data structure to store users).

I want create a program to store and read users into binary file. My problem is when I run the main.cpp (first run) below to save and read file, it reads and displays normal data. But when I run the main.cpp (second run) to only read file which was saved just now, it does not work properly.

I don't know why this can happen. My User class attributes types are char*, char* and bool.

```
// main.cpp (first run)

UserList userList;

User user1("admin", "root", 1);
User user2("aaaa", "dcasf", 1);
User user3("user3", "abcd", 0);
User user4("user4", "bbbb", 0);
userList.add(user1);
userList.add(user2);
userList.add(user3);
userList.add(user4);

userList.saveFile("user.txt");
userList.loadFile("user.txt");
userList.display();
```

```
// main.cpp (second run)

UserList userList;

userList.loadFile("user.txt");
userList.display();
```

```
// userlist.h

#ifndef USERLIST_H
#define USERLIST_H

#include "user.h"
using namespace std;


struct UserNode{
    User user;
    UserNode* next = NULL;

    UserNode(){}

    UserNode(User user){
        this->user = user;
    }

    UserNode(User user, UserNode* next){
        this->user = user;
        this->next = next;
    }
};


class UserList{

public:
    UserList(){
        size = 0;
        isEmpty = true;

        head = NULL;
    };

    UserList(const UserList& userList);

    ~UserList(){
        clearAll();
    }

    void add(User user){
        if(head == NULL){
            head = new UserNode();
            head->user = user;
        }else{
            UserNode* temp = head;

            while(temp->next != NULL){
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            temp->next = new UserNode();
            temp->next->user = user;
        }
    }

    void clearAll(){
        while(head != NULL){
            UserNode* temp = head;
            head = head->next;

            delete temp;
        }

        head = NULL;
    }

    User find(string username){
        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->user.getUsername() == username){
                return temp->user;
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }

        User user;
        return user;
    }

    bool contain(string username){
        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->user.getUsername() == username){
                return true;
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void display(){
        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            cout << temp->user.getUsername() << "\t" << temp->user.getPassword() << "\t" << temp->user.getIsAdmin() << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void saveFile(string filename){
        ofstream output;
        output.open(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);

        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            User user = temp->user;

            output.write((char*)&user, sizeof(user));

            temp = temp->next;
        }

        output.close();
    }

    void loadFile(string filename){
        clearAll();

        ifstream input;
        input.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);

        User user;
        while(input.read((char*)&user, sizeof(user))){  // read 1 user from file
            add(user);
        }

        input.close();
    }

private:
    int size;
    bool isEmpty;

    UserNode* head;
};
```

```
// user.h

#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

using namespace std;


class User{

public:
    User(){}

    User(char* username, char* password, bool isAdmin){
        this->username = username;
        this->password = password;
        this->isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    ~User(){}

    void setUsername(char* username){
        this->username = username;
    }

    void setPassword(char* password){
        this->password = password;
    }

    char* getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    char* getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    bool getIsAdmin(){
        return isAdmin;
    }

private:

    char* username;
    char* password;
    bool isAdmin;
};


#endif
```

Comment: A pointer that you have saved to a file is very unlikely to point to a valid object when you read it back (unless you do it immediately after writing, while those objects still exist). You need to read about "serialization".

Comment: @molbdnilo But I run another program with same context, save a Box class object in a file and read it back in seperate runtime. It works properly.

Comment: But what has your `Box` class got to do with the code shown?  Does it have any pointer data members?

Comment: @john Probably because your `Box` class only contained numbers or arrays and no pointers. (But you can't really tell if a C++ program is correct by observing what it does - undefined behaviour can do what you expect for all the wrong reasons.)

Comment: `char*` is always a pointer type. A value of type `char*` is always a pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo Both User class or Box class don't have pointer attribute. They only have char*, bool, or int. Is char* considered as pointer attribute too? If that, should I replace char* to char[ ] to place string object?

Comment: @G.M. Box class is just for testing case. Its attributes are just int and char* type.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok. Is that any suggestion to store class object into binary file for my case?

Comment: Your options are the same as has already been mentioned: 1) don't use pointers, or 2) implement proper serialization.

Answer (score 0):

When you write into the file, It clears the already written data. You should use append mode for writing into the file

Comment: My problem is not that. My problem is that when I save into file and read the file when program runs, it works normally. But when I only run readFile() to read the file saved just now, it does not work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you serialize a struct with a char pointer inside , only serializes the address of the char pointer. We have to carry the length of the strings and serialize each string with this length information so that we can exactly de-serialize the struct .

```
// userlist.h

#ifndef USERLIST_H
#define USERLIST_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "user.h"
using namespace std;


struct UserNode{
    User user;
    UserNode* next = NULL;

    UserNode(){}

    UserNode(User user){
        this->user = user;
    }

    UserNode(User user, UserNode* next){
        this->user = user;
        this->next = next;
    }
};


class UserList{

public:
    UserList(){
        size = 0;
        isEmpty = true;

        head = NULL;
    };

    UserList(const UserList& userList);

    ~UserList(){
        clearAll();
    }

    void add(User user){
        if(head == NULL){
            head = new UserNode();
            head->user = user;
        }else{
            UserNode* temp = head;

            while(temp->next != NULL){
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            temp->next = new UserNode();
            temp->next->user = user;
        }
    }

    void clearAll(){
        while(head != NULL){
            UserNode* temp = head;
            head = head->next;

            delete temp;
        }

        head = NULL;
    }

    User find(string username){
        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->user.getUsername() == username){
                return temp->user;
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }

        User user;
        return user;
    }

    bool contain(string username){
        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->user.getUsername() == username){
                return true;
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void display(){
        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            cout << temp->user.getUsername() << "\t" << temp->user.getPassword() << "\t" << temp->user.getIsAdmin() << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void saveFile(string filename){
        ofstream output;
        output.open(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);

        UserNode* temp = head;

        while(temp != NULL){
            User user = temp->user;
            output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&user.sz_user), sizeof(int));
            output.write(user.getUsername(), user.sz_user * sizeof(char));
            output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&user.sz_pass), sizeof(int));
            output.write(user.getPassword(), user.sz_pass * sizeof(char));
            output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&user.admin_state) , sizeof(int));
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        output.close();
    }

    void loadFile(string filename){
        clearAll();

        ifstream input;
        input.open(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);

        User user;       
        while(input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&user.sz_user), sizeof(int))){  // read 1 user from file
            char* usr = new char[user.sz_user];
            input.read(usr, user.sz_user * sizeof(char));
            user.setUsername(usr);

            input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&user.sz_pass), sizeof(int));
            char* pass = new char[user.sz_pass];
            input.read(pass, user.sz_pass * sizeof(char));
            user.setPassword(pass);
            
            int adm ;
            input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&adm),  sizeof(int));
            user.setAdmin(adm);

            add(user);
        } 
       
        input.close();
    }

private:
    int size;
    bool isEmpty;

    UserNode* head;
};
#endif
```

And small changes in the User class . (You may carry the serialization read and writes above into this class to make more styled code.)

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

using namespace std;
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

class User{

public:
    User(){}

    User(char* username, char* password, bool isAdmin){
        this->username = username;
        this->password = password;       
        this->isAdmin = isAdmin;
        sz_user = strlen(username);
        sz_pass = strlen(password);
        admin_state = isAdmin ? 1: 0;       
    }

    ~User(){}

    void setUsername(char* username){
        this->username = username;
    }

    void setPassword(char* password){
        this->password = password;
    }

    void setAdmin(int adm) { isAdmin = adm ? true : false ; }

    char* getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    char* getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    bool getIsAdmin(){
        return isAdmin;
    }

    int sz_user;
    int sz_pass;
    int admin_state;
    
private:

    char* username;  
    char* password;
    bool isAdmin;
    
};


#endif
```